# Need help writing a recursive function to find descendants of a person. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter, dataset

I'm trying to write a function to find the descendants of a person. The data I have is set up in an array and is formatted like this:

```
    {
        "id": 159819275,
        "firstName": "Jasmine",
        "lastName": "Bob",
        "gender": "female",
        "dob": "12/18/1969",
        "height": 58,
        "weight": 156,
        "eyeColor": "blue",
        "occupation": "assistant",
        "parents": [409574486, 260451248],
        "currentSpouse": 951747547
    },
```

The function I wrote takes in the the ID of the person whose descendants I am looking for, the array of people, and creates a new array that holds the descendants.

```
function findDescendants (id, people, descendantsArray = []){

 descendantsArray = people.filter(function(el){
      return el.parents[0] === id || el.parents[1 === id] //id works if it's a variable, but if it's a array it won't work. otherwise function is good 
    })    
  displayPeople(descendantsArray)  //calls a method that alerts the descendant's names into a string
  id = [];   //resets the id and turns it into an array
  for(let i = 0; i<descendantsArray.length; i++){
    id[i] = descendantsArray[i].id
  }           //puts the id's of the listed descendants into the array id

  if (descendantsArray.length === 0){
    return descendantsArray;
  } 
  else {
    findDescendants(id, people, descendantsArray)
  } //sends in the array id, the data set people, and the descendantsArray (which contains the children of the person in question. 
}
```

My problem is that when I call the array the second time, the filter doesn't compare the el.parents to all elements in id and I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
descendantsArray = people.filter(function(el){
      return el.parents[0] === id || el.parents[1 === id] //id works if it's a variable, but if it's a array it won't work. otherwise function is good 
    })
```

what I would like this statement to do is filter out all elements in people whose "parents: " contain any of the elements in the array of id. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `el.parents[1 === id]` You probably meant this? `el.parents[1] === id`

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```js
const getDescendents = (people, id) =>
  people .filter (({parents = []}) => parents .includes (id))
         .flatMap (person => [person, ... getDescendents (people, person.id)])
```

If we had a tree like this:

```
                                 Alice + Bob    
                                       |
                       +---------------+--------------+
                       |                              |
           Charlie + Denise                        Edward + Francine    
                   |                                      |
            +------+-------+                              |
            |              |                              |
  Geroge + Helen         Irwin + Jean                 Kayleigh     
                               |         
                               |
                               |
                             Leroy
```

and we called `getDescendents(people, 1)` (where Alice has id `1`), we would get back the objects representing these people: `[Denise, Helen, Irwin, Leroy, Edward, Kayleigh]`.  That involves a depth-first, pre-order traversal of the data.  If we wanted to sort (by id or whatever), we could do that after the call or -- with some minor performance degradation -- as a final step of the function:

```js
const getDescendents = (people, id) =>
  people .filter (({parents = []}) => parents .includes (id))
         .flatMap (person => [person, ... getDescendents (people, person.id)])
         .sort (({id: a}, {id: b}) => a - b)


const people = [{name: 'Alice', id: 1, parents: []}, {name: 'Bob', id: 2, parents: []}, {name: 'Charlie', id: 3, parents: []}, {name: 'Denise', id: 4, parents: [1, 2]}, {name: 'Edward', id: 5, parents: [1, 2]}, {name: 'Francine', id: 6, parents: []}, {name: 'George', id: 7, parents: []}, {name: 'Helen', id: 8, parents: [3, 4]}, {name: 'Irwin', id: 9, parents: [3, 4]}, {name: 'Jean', id: 10, parents: []}, {name: 'Kayleigh', id: 11, parents: [5, 6]}, {name: 'Leroy', id: 12, parents: [9, 10]}]

people .forEach (
  ({name, id}) => console .log (
    `${name} ==> [${getDescendents(people, id).map(({name}) => name).join(', ')}]`
  )
)

console .log ('Denise\'s descendents: ', getDescendents (people, 4))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```